# Camel ProducerTemplate requestBody and return type

Tags: apache-camel, producer

`ProducerTemplate` require a non null body parameter when the response type is specified.
In my case, the body must be null, because I use the bean component, and I have a non parameter bean, parameters being then injected in that bean and the route will continue to others beans, this time with a body.

```java
AType response = producer.requestBody(nonNullBody, AType.class);
```

This won't work:

```java
//cause ambiguous type error 
AType response = producer.requestBody(null, AType.class); 

//Unsupported method signature
AType response = producer.requestBody(AType.class);
```

Is there a turn-around beside passing a dummy body parameter ?

Also, is there a way to use a `Collection` as `AType`, without having to cast the result ? I tried to wrap it into another object, and it doesn't work.

Notes

For now, I use `producer.requestBody(null)`, followed by a ugly cast.
Would have been cool if we could do `producer.requestBody()` instead.

Unfortunately, Camel does't support more than one body parameter, which also would have been very helpful eg:

`requestBody(String.. args, Class<T> type)`

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried casting null to the required type already? I.e. `(AType) null`?

Comment: yes I did. It pass, eg (Object)null but not super clean. (String)null is ambiguous at compile time

Comment: You can use `FluentProducerTemplate` instead